# Ruby: Circular Dependancy autoloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vmware, autoload, theforeman

I am trying to patch a [foreman bug](http://projects.theforeman.org/issues/14160) where they don't disable network boot after build and turn it back on when you want to rebuild a host. It looks like I just need to add some code to the "built" method in:

./app/controllers/unattended_controller.rb

```
def built
    logger.info "#{controller_name}: #{@host.name} is Built!"
    update_ip if Setting[:update_ip_from_built_request]
    head(@host.built ? :created : :conflict)
 end
```

and the "setBuild" method in:

./app/models/host/managed.rb

```
def setBuild
  self.build = true
  self.save
  errors.empty?
end
```

Borrowing from line 79 of [foreman_bootdisk.rb](https://github.com/theforeman/foreman_bootdisk/blob/master/lib/foreman_bootdisk/engine.rb) and [modify_vm_cdrom.rb](https://github.com/fog/fog-vsphere/blob/master/lib/fog/vsphere/requests/compute/modify_vm_cdrom.rb) for inspiration,
 I have come up with something along the lines of:

```
def setBuild
  load '/usr/share/foreman/app/models/compute_resources/foreman/model/vmware.rb'
  if ComputeResources::Foreman::Model::Vmware.available?
      vm_reconfig_hardware('instance_uuid' => params[:token], 'hardware_spec' => {'bootOptions'=>['network', 'disk']})
  end
  self.build = true
  self.save
  errors.empty?
end
```

The problem is that I get the error,

> Oops, we're sorry but something went wrong Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant ComputeResources::Foreman::Model::Vmware

I have done some reading on this and hear that the problem is probably with rail's autoload, but I have tried fixing this with load and require (I was trying to avoid the autoload function which I hear is [deprecated](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5653)), but despite having tried both, I continue to get this error and I am unsure why. What am i doing differently than  the coders of foreman_bootdisk.rb to get this error that they aren't? Whey doesn't [vmware.rb](https://github.com/iNecas/foreman-build/blob/master/lib/foreman/model/vmware.rb) seem to want to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def setBuild
  vm_reconfig_hardware(
    'instance_uuid' => params[:token],
    'hardware_spec' => {'bootOptions'=>['network', 'disk']}
  ) if Fog::Compute.providers.include?(:vsphere)

  self.build = true
  self.save
  errors.empty?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by incorrect constant name. Did you tried something like this?

```
def setBuild
  if Foreman::Model::Vmware.available?
    vm_reconfig_hardware('instance_uuid' => params[:token], 'hardware_spec' => {'bootOptions'=>['network', 'disk']})
  end
  self.build = true
  self.save
  errors.empty?
end
```

In Foreman source code there is no constant ComputeResources (with s at the end), but when you try to use it in rails console it will work. It is because rails autoloading is kind of creating module on the fly because there is directory with name `compute_resources`.

Comment: That give me the error `"Oops, we're sorry but something went wrong undefined method \`available?' for #<Class:0x0000000ad76c48>"` instead. This is the same error I get if I use `ComputeResource::Foreman::Model::Vmware.available` or a known bad namespace, like `ComputeResources::thisisbad::Model::Vmware.available`. The fact that I got something other than "undefined method `available?'" is what made me think I was headed down the right track in the first place.

Comment: Can you update your question about some versions of foreman and what system are you using? Did you changed any rails configuration options or monkey-patched it?

Can you test using those classes in rails console? Can you try to load different classes (Foreman::Model::EC2 for example)? Do you have the same problem?

You can also try ::Foreman::Model::Vmware.

Or maybe you can just use the actual implementation of available? method: `Fog::Compute.providers.include?(:vsphere)`

Comment: It is Foreman 1.11. Default install of Katello, so only any monkey-patching Red Hat may have done to get the Katello stack to work. I'll try a few other things and report back.